# Conflict between onTouchListener and onCreateContextMenu?

Tags: android, contextmenu, conflict, ontouchlistener

whats up??

I was creating a movable textview, so I could drag and drop it throught the whole screen... then, I decided to add Contextual menu to it, so I did it, but contextual menu only appear if I disable onTouchListener, so my here is my question:
 is there any way to make them compatible?

I will post the code later if necesary

Thanks in advance!!! ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A context menu is generally started with a long touch.  You initiate dragging with a long touch, you will need to initiate one or the other by some other means.  I had a similar issue and got around it by placing the move command in the context menu.

I did it by setting a "moving" variable to true and highligting the control.  The user then draggs the control and when released, set moving to false and save the position.

Comment: What you mean is to put a boolean in onTouch, and, when not moving, display context menu, isn't it???